# What happens to permanents modified by effects like Chance for Glory that change their card type?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

For instance, [Chance for Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChance%20for%20Glory%5d) grants creatures indefinite indestructibility. What if said creature was a temporarily animated artifact, land, or enchantment that then loses the creature card type at a later time?

I can see arguments for both versions: since they were an eligible target their text has been modified and they don't lose the indestructibility since it's just on the permanent, at the same time, chance for glory does specifically say creatures are granted indestructibility, really not sure about this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will still be indestructible. This is because granting indestructible is a continuous effect that happens as part of Chance for Glory resolving, and the set of objects affected is determined at that time. Once the creature has been granted indestructible, there is nothing that would cause it to lose that just because it changes types.

Note that this is different than a static ability such as [Eldrazi Monument](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEldrazi%20Monument%5d). In that case, it only affects creatures, and anything that stops being a creature would stop being affected.

> 611.2c If a continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability modifies the characteristics or changes the controller of any objects, the set of objects it affects is determined when that continuous effect begins. After that point, the set won’t change. (Note that this works differently than a continuous effect from a static ability.)